# How to passthrough Wifi DNS and internet access to DHCP client

Tags: linux, dns, routing, iptables

I have a laptop that connects to wifi for internet access. This computer is running Linux (Fedora), and it is acting as a DHCP server for another (ubuntu linaro) computer that does not have a wifi adapter. The laptop and the other computer connect through a crossover cable through their respective standard ethernet ports. So laptop is DHCP server, and other computer is DHCP client.

I have verified that the other computer is correctly getting a DHCP address from the laptop. However, `ping www.yahoo.com` doesn't work. I can also see in `/etc/resolv.conf` of the DHCP client computer that the correct settings are there from the DHCP server.

I have not made any changes to `iptables`.

**My question is, how do I tell the laptop to pass DNS requests and internet access from the dhcp client to the wifi network? Do I need to run a DNS daemon also?**

```
[idf@localhost ~]$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
1

[idf@localhost ~]$
```

Here is the output of ifconfig -a on the laptop (DHCP server)

```
[idf@localhost ~]$ ifconfig -a
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::28c:faff:feac:2de0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:8c:fa:ac:2d:e0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 899  bytes 123800 (120.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 8  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1338  bytes 131506 (128.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6557  bytes 1142539 (1.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6557  bytes 1142539 (1.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe0c:77c4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:0c:77:c4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11  bytes 1174 (1.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:0c:77:c4  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.128.231.168  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 10.128.231.255
        inet6 fe80::2ae3:47ff:febd:bc4a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 28:e3:47:bd:bc:4a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10004803  bytes 10357195255 (9.6 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7473957  bytes 1022964388 (975.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[idf@localhost ~]$
```

Here is my dhcpd.conf file

```
[idf@localhost ~]$ more /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf 
ddns-update-style interim;                                   # Required for dhcp 3.0+ / Red Hat 8.0+
ignore client-updates;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

        range 192.168.1.128 192.168.1.254;                   # Range of IP addresses to be issued to DHCP clients
           option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;    # Default subnet mask to be used by DHCP clients
           option broadcast-address        192.168.1.255;    # Default broadcastaddress to be used by DHCP clients
           option routers                  192.168.1.1;      # Default gateway to be used by DHCP clients
           option domain-name              "synctrading.org";
           option domain-name-servers      192.168.1.1;           # Default DNS to be used by DHCP clients
           option netbios-name-servers     192.168.1.100;    # Specify a WINS server for MS/Windows clients.
                                                             # (Optional. Specify if used on your network)

#         DHCP requests are not forwarded. Applies when there is more than one ethernet device and forwarding is configured.
#       option ipforwarding off;

        default-lease-time 21600;                            # Amount of time in seconds that a client may keep the IP address
        max-lease-time 43200;

        option time-offset              -18000;              # Eastern Standard Time
#       option ntp-servers              192.168.1.1;         # Default NTP server to be used by DHCP clients
#       option netbios-name-servers     192.168.1.1;
# --- Selects point-to-point node (default is hybrid). Don't change this unless you understand Netbios very well
#       option netbios-node-type 2;
}

[idf@localhost ~]$
```

**EDIT 1**

After folllowing the instructions below (I changed the nameservers to google dns in the dhcpd.conf file), I did a `sudo tcpdump -i enp1s0` the laptop. Then from the DHCP client, I tried `ping www.yahoo.com` and some interesting stuff prints out in the dump on the DHCP server. `"admin prohibited"` is interesting, but I don't know what it means or how to fix it.

```
22:46:31.697964 IP 192.168.1.128.42318 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 15883+ A? www.yahoo.com. (31)
22:46:31.698068 IP localhost.localdomain > 192.168.1.128: ICMP host google-public-dns-a.google.com unreachable - admin prohibited, length 67
22:46:31.698593 IP 192.168.1.128.56805 > alu7750testscr.xyz1.gblx.mgmt.Level3.net.domain: 15883+ A? www.yahoo.com. (31)
22:46:31.698683 IP localhost.localdomain > 192.168.1.128: ICMP host alu7750testscr.xyz1.gblx.mgmt.Level3.net unreachable - admin prohibited, length 67
22:46:31.699123 IP 192.168.1.128.40441 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 15883+ A? www.yahoo.com. (31)
22:46:31.699180 IP localhost.localdomain > 192.168.1.128: ICMP host google-public-dns-a.google.com unreachable - admin prohibited, length 67
22:46:31.699598 IP 192.168.1.128.60984 > alu7750testscr.xyz1.gblx.mgmt.Level3.net.domain: 15883+ A? www.yahoo.com. (31)
22:46:36.706262 IP 192.168.1.128.46076 > alu7750testscr.xyz1.gblx.mgmt.Level3.net.domain: 5928+ A? www.yahoo.com.synctrading.org. (47)
22:46:36.706356 IP localhost.localdomain > 192.168.1.128: ICMP host alu7750testscr.xyz1.gblx.mgmt.Level3.net unreachable - admin prohibited, length 83
22:46:36.707346 IP 192.168.1.128.ssh > localhost.localdomain.41245: Flags [P.], seq 1661:1729, ack 576, win 330, options [nop,nop,TS val 35236 ecr 4294953343], length 68
22:46:36.707409 IP localhost.localdomain.41245 > 192.168.1.128.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1729, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294958364 ecr 35236], length 0
22:46:36.707781 IP 192.168.1.128.ssh > localhost.localdomain.41245: Flags [P.], seq 1729:1765, ack 576, win 330, options [nop,nop,TS val 35236 ecr 4294958364], length 36
22:46:36.707823 IP localhost.localdomain.41245 > 192.168.1.128.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1765, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294958364 ecr 35236], length 0
22:46:36.710622 IP 192.168.1.128.ssh > localhost.localdomain.41245: Flags [P.], seq 1765:1833, ack 576, win 330, options [nop,nop,TS val 35237 ecr 4294958364], length 68
22:46:36.710663 IP localhost.localdomain.41245 > 192.168.1.128.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1833, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294958367 ecr 35237], length 0
22:46:46.577998 AoE length 46, Ver 1, Flags: [none]
```

**EDIT 2**

```
[idf@localhost ~]$ sudo iptables -L -n
[sudo] password for idf: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
INPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FORWARD_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_FedoraWorkstation (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_FedoraWorkstation (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
IN_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
IN_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
IN_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
IN_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_FedoraWorkstation (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_FedoraWorkstation_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
IN_FedoraWorkstation_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
IN_FedoraWorkstation_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_FedoraWorkstation_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:1025:65535 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:1025:65535 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_FedoraWorkstation_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_FedoraWorkstation_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
[idf@localhost ~]$
```

**EDIT 3**

```
[idf@localhost ~]$ sudo iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
PREROUTING_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
PREROUTING_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24        
RETURN     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255     
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  udp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    
POSTROUTING_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
POSTROUTING_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
POST_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
POST_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
POST_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
POST_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
POST_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POST_FedoraWorkstation (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
POST_FedoraWorkstation_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
POST_FedoraWorkstation_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
POST_FedoraWorkstation_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POST_FedoraWorkstation_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POST_FedoraWorkstation_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POST_FedoraWorkstation_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
PRE_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
PRE_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
PRE_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
PRE_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
PRE_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain PREROUTING_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain PRE_FedoraWorkstation (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
PRE_FedoraWorkstation_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
PRE_FedoraWorkstation_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
PRE_FedoraWorkstation_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain PRE_FedoraWorkstation_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain PRE_FedoraWorkstation_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain PRE_FedoraWorkstation_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: But does *ping -c1 8.8.8.8* work?

Comment: This does not look like a DNS problem as much as a routing problem.  Are you able to get to the wider Internet from your Linaro device ?  My guess is that your router (ie the adsl modem or equivalent - not the Fedora box) does not know how to reach the 10.128.231.0/25 network - Either that or you need to bridge the Interfaces on your Fedora box rather then route them.

Comment: @davigo, yeah, I just don't know what the way to bridge an ethernet NIC to a wireless NIC. I looked at brctl, but wireless doesn't play nice.

Comment: @Marius, even if I try to ping an ip address from the dhcp client that I can ping from the laptop it doesn't work. So pinging 8.8.8.8 won't work either.

Comment: I installed parprouted on Fedora and said sudo parprouted enp1s0 wlp2s0, but I still cannot ping an ip address from the dhcplient.

Comment: Do you know what service is configuring iptables? Can you add to your question a dump of `iptables -L -n` and `iptables -L -n -t nat`?

Comment: See Edit 2 and Edit 3

Comment: I think the problem is that you have something already configuring iptables, probably `firewalld` on fedora, and so any rules we add are applied after these, and they may be rejecting packets before they get to the new rules. Replace the -A by -I in the iptables commands to insert at the start. Also we may get more comprehensible output from iptables-save instead of iptables -L [-t nat]. Your best answer is to the find the configuration command for firewalld and use it to describe your setup so it can setup iptables in its way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
domain-name-servers      192.168.1.1;
```

by the address of the dns server used by the laptop, or configure a dns cache server on your laptop. Use commands like `nslookup` or `host` to test the dns access on the client.

You need to enable masquerading on the laptop with iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o <wifi_interface> -j MASQUERADE
```

Perhaps you already have some iptables configuration in use (this is not my strong point). Try setting the default policy for the nat table with

```
iptables -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Note you can always see what packets are passing on an interface using

```
sudo tcpdump -i <name_of_interface>
```

If you do this on both interfaces at once you can see where a packet is lost or rejected by the laptop.

You may have a service which has already configured iptables, eg **firewalld** on fedora. It's best to try and use its configuration tool to make any changes. For example,

```
firewall-cmd --add-masquerade
```

but you also need to setup an *internal* or *trusted* zone for your ethernet network (sorry, I dont know anything more about this).

Comment: Even if I try to ping an ip address from the dhcp client that I can ping from the laptop it doesn't work.

Comment: @meuth, much closer!!!! I am able to ping ips, but dns is not working (I have not changed the domain-name-servers as you state above yet because I don't know how to find out) However, I think it is downhill from here. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the configuration of the dhcpd.conf to add the nameservers that my laptop uses when it connects to the wifi. I can see them in /etc/resolv.conf on the dhcp client. However, I can't ping www.yahoo.com but I can ping the nameservers themselves! Maybe DNS needs a similar iptables entry?

Comment: Found this answer here  http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1242667  , not sure how to do this to my setup:  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Comment: @Ivan those rules say accept all packets from eth2 (in your case your ethernet) being forwarded out of eth0 (your wifi). In the reverse direction only accept those packets that are for connections that first got made in the ethernet-to-wifi direction. You can apply these rules.

Comment: I added your iptables commands. I then ran tcpdump on the laptop (dhcpserver) see the original post under Edit.

Comment: Above, I mean Edit 1

Comment: @Ivan I added the only `firewalld` configuration command I know.

Comment: meuh, the firewalld-cmd command did it! I have a mess that I need to clean up apparently with my iptables & firewalld. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your DHCP configuration looks fine. It might be that you do not have a DNS resolver at 192.168.1.1 or it doesn't run dnsmasq service. What sort of device is your gateway?

Comment: Even if I try to ping an ip address from the dhcp client that I can ping from the laptop it doesn't work